# How can i make a users top list in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm building a website with a points system.

(Let's say if a user ads a post he will receive 5 Points)

I'm using:

```
SELECT id, username, active, points 
    FROM users 
    WHERE active='1' 
    ORDER BY points DESC
```

to display the users top and also i can display (with a while loop) their **place**.

But how can i **display** their **place** on their personal page, or any other page?

And as a secondary question, how can i direct the user to **their place** in the top?
(If he is .... on the 1000th place)

Answer (score 1):

How about counting the users that have more points than me:

```
select count(*) from users where points > $my_points;
```

Comment: If the top players all have 100 points, that means the player who has 99 points will be ranked 6th. So the ranking would go from 1 straight to 6. that might look weird, when people ask what happened to ranks 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Comment: Well, I think it's unavoidable, as there is no second order sort criteria defined on the ranking system. So you might simply change the wording from "Your rank is 6" to "You're tied for 6th rank."

Comment: there's a default second criteria in Mysql, the id!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, username, active, points, @place = @place + 1
    FROM users, (select @place := 0) p
    WHERE active='1' 
    ORDER BY points DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but it worked for me after I modified the select `@place = @place + 1` to `@place := @place + 1`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you if you want to show a player's rank or standing based on number of points, you want `rownum`. I don't think MySQL has a rownum feature, but I found a link that shows you how to fake it: http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/ (disclaimer: I haven't tried this).

... of course I have ask what do you do if two players have the same number of points? Give them the same rank? That could get a bit more complicated, but maybe the solution I linked to can be adapted?

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen most browser-based games etc.. that have a ranking system do is basically do a query just like that except put the results into a "ranks" table and only update that table once a day or so. Then to find out a person's place, simply query that "ranks" table and grab the value from an auto_inc'd number column. You can of course do this every single query but that's not very efficient, and showing updated ranks once a day or whatever is usually acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question you could use the following query, this will return users points.

```
SELECT points FROM users WHERE id='$userid'
```

However i dont understand your second question can you clarify?